# I want to create a SQL query for calculating the running total for each customer on a daily basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to write a SQL query for calculating the running total for each customer on a daily basis.

For example :

```
CustomerID   TranDate  TranAmount RunningTotal
-----------------------------------------------
C1             8/1/17    $10        $10
C2             8/1/17    $15        $15
C1             8/2/17    $20        $30
C2             8/2/17    $30        $45
C3             8/3/17    $50        $50
```

I was able to create running total If there is only 1 customer in the table but having difficulty when there are many .

Thank you in advance.

Please let me know if you need any further information .

Comment: Post the code that you've done already please.

Comment: Isn't the 4th column the column record for RunningTotal?

Comment: SELECT ARID,ARTransactionID, ARTransactionAmount,
(SELECT SUM(ARTransactionAmount)
FROM #XXX T2
WHERE T2.ARTransactionID <= T1.ARTransactionID) AS RunningTotal

FROM #XXX T1
order by ARTransactionID

Comment: yes 4th column is running total for individual customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT A.Customer,A.TranDate, 
SUM(B.TranAmount) AS RunningTotal FROM 
TableA AS A Inner Join TableA AS B
ON A.CustomerID=B.CustomerID AND 
A.TranDate<=B.TranDate
GROUP BY A.Customer,A.TranDate
```

This will work for table with relatively small number of records. For large data volume, this needs to be refined.

Comment: Thank you . As you said , it is working for small data volume . I have ~3.5 million records in table . This query is not working even after waiting 20 minutes.

Comment: Use a batching logic for batch of 100 /1000